# npm isn't installing on ubuntu. Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, npm

I have install nodejs and npm on ubuntu but i am getting Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

I already run this command

```
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org"
```

And also removed proxy

here is the error log- https://gist.github.com/TheSanto/fdbc33f963b9d75bb4d23038cb27dabf

Comment: Doesn't look like you did a very good job of "removing proxy", it's trying to use one.

Comment: silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: tunneling socket could not be established, Looks like connection issue try with a direct connection